# linking various divs for clicking functions using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have 3 sections. Group, Category, Subcategory.

There are 2 groups: grp1, grp2
For grp1, there are 3 category: grp1_C1, grp1_C2, grp1_C3
For grp 2, there are 2 category: grp2_C1, grp2_C2

For grp1_C1, there are 3 subgcategory: grp1_C1_S1, grp1_C1_S2 and so on

All the sections will be fetched dynamically from the data and thus the linking etc has to be done using jquery.

What I want to do is that I show 2 group buttons. When I Click on any of the groups, I want to show the Categories linked to it, and then when I click any of the category in it, I want to show the subsequent sub-categories in it.

I will create divs for all.

```
<div id='group'>
    <div id='grp1' class="group"></div>
    <div id='grp2' class="group"></div>
</div>


<div id='cat'>
    <div id='grp1_cat' class="cat">
       <div id='grp1_cat1' class="cat"></div>
       <div id='grp1_cat2' class="cat"></div>
    </div>
    <div id='grp2_cat' class="cat">
       <div id='grp2_cat1' class="cat"></div>
       <div id='grp2_cat2' class="cat"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

similarly for sub-categories.

Now, when I click on group1, I want only group 1 categories visible, and then when I click a category only the linked sub-category visible.

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried something? Can you post your jQuery code that we see what have you done so far?

Comment: no..have not been able to figure out the starting step itself. Am not very experienced with jquery

Answer (score 1):

See this : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aGPcb/)

```
$('#cat > .cat:not(:first)').hide();
$('#group').on('click', '.group', function(){
   $('#cat > .cat').hide();
   $('#' + this.id + '_cat').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
$('#cat > .cat').hide();
$('#group').on('click', '.group', function(){
    $('#cat > .cat').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '_cat').show();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dyCpm/1/)

Comment: what does #cat > .cat do?? Please explain. This seems to be working, so if I get it, I will apply it to the entire segments

Comment: `#cat > .cat` means all direct children of element with id `cat` having class `cat`.

Comment: another question..after I add subcategory. When I click on any group, it shows the category, but I also want to show the first sub-category.  So the code should be something like ('#' + $(this).attr('id') + /../:first).show(); but this is not working. /../ is the regular expression for any category, basically any subcategory which start with the group id I clicked

Comment: :(. Ok just tell this - how to say that show the first subcateogry in group one.  ('#grp1' + 'anycategory' + ':first').show();

Comment: is anycategory an id, with out the mark up it will be difficult, at least edit your question to show the subcategories

Comment: for example grp1cat1sub1, grp1cat1sub2, grp1cat2sub1, grp1cat2sub2. Now when I click on grp1, it shows the grp1cat1 and grp1cat2. What I want to do is that along with cat1 and cat2, i also want to show grp1cat1sub1, grp1cat1sub2 by default. That is even without clicking grp1cat1, it should show by default. So the first entry always shows by default. So ANY CATEGORY means any ID of any category in grp1. I am only interested in the first sub-category in grp1. But since Subcategory ID has Category ID involved, I am stuck